# Ajax request max execution timing out

Tags: php, loops

While using this code to gather data using an Ajax XHTMLRequest I'm getting an PHP Max execution timeout

```
if(isset($_GET['func']) and $_GET['func'] == 'feed') {
    global $ado;
    $old_msg_id = $_GET['old_msg_id']; 
    $result = $ado->exec("SELECT * FROM `earnings` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row = $ado->fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $last_msg_id = $row['id']; 
    }
    while($last_msg_id <= $old_msg_id) {
        $result = $ado->exec("SELECT * FROM `earnings` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
        while($row = $ado->fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $last_msg_id = $row['id'];
        }
    }
    $response = array();
    $response['msg'] = 'new';
    $response['old_msg_id'] = $last_msg_id;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

The error I'm receiving in the error_log is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /ajax.php on line 165
```

Line 165 is the following :

```
while($last_msg_id <= $old_msg_id) {
```

I currently don't see a problem with the code, any hints as to what's wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## JS level

In AJAX you can post the time out like below,

```
       jQuery.ajax({
           url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
           success: function (result) {                               
                returned_value=result;
           },
           timeout: 10000,
           async: false
        });
```

## PHP level

If you are getting PHP you can change it in the PHP.ini

```
max_execution_time = 30 //make it like 300
```

**Else** in your PHP code use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

> When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero.
>   In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25
>   seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is
>   made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out.

**Also** make sure that those while loops are not never ending loops.

Comment: Thanks for this information, although it's not the solution to my problem, i want to stop it timing out if possible because it's continuing with the jQuery call because all the script isn't running.

Comment: if you read it, changing max_execution_time will do the trick for you

Comment: Changing max_execution_time is not a very efficient way of dealing with the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your two while loops are taking too long to execute, Is there allot of data in the databases.

Comment: Nope, only like 1,000 records

Comment: Try increasing `max_execution_time` for now and then echo the time and every part of the process. Look at the time differences and then look for what function taking the most amount of time and tell me.